# React convert function to class and call variable from function to class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js, i need to convert function to class and after that i need to call a variable from another function to the class

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = ({cartLength}) => {

    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div className="container">
                <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Ecommerce</NavLink>
                <div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/cart"}><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-2"
                                                                          aria-hidden="true" />Cart {cartLength ? `(${cartLength})`: ''}</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      cartLength: state.shop.cart.length
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Header);
```

From the above code 
I am accessing the  **cartLength** value from mapStateToProps function to Header function ,

Now i am converting function to class

`const Header = ({cartLength}) => {`

to

`class Header extends React.Component {`

my modified code

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';



// const Header = ({ cartLength }) => {
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cartLength: '',

        }
    }




    render() {
        console.log(" cartlength from main class:", this.state.cartLength, this.props.cartLength)
        return (
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div className="container">
                <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Ecommerce</NavLink>
                <div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/cart"}><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-2" aria-hidden="true" />Cart {this.state.cartLength ? `(${this.state.cartLength})` : ''}</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      cartLength: state.shop.cart.length
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Header);
```

I need **cartLength** value from mapStateToProps function to Header class ,
How can access the value in the

If anyone know the solution please tell me ..

Comment: Are you saying `this.props.cartLength` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the the solution by using 
`this.props.cartLength`

now i can get the cartLength values from mapStateToProps , and i didn't mention any value in

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // cartLength: '',

        }
    }
```

directly i can access the value by using props

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';



// const Header = ({ cartLength }) => {
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // cartLength: '',

        }
    }




    render() {
        console.log(" cartlength from main class:", this.state.cartLength, this.props.cartLength)
        return (
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div className="container">
                <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Ecommerce</NavLink>
                <div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/cart"}><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-2" aria-hidden="true" />Cart {this.props.cartLength ? `(${this.props.cartLength})` : ''}</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    console.log(state, 'state has changed');
    return {
        cartLength: state.shop.cart.length

    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Header);
```

Answer (score 0):

`cartLength` is available in `props`. Either you can change `this.state.cartLength` to `this.props.cartLength` or in constructor you can do like this:

```
Edited:

this.state = {
  cartLength: props.cartLength
}
```

Comment: I guess your suggestion code is located in `constructor`, then you may not be able to use `this`. So `this.props.cartLength` might not be available. You may use `props.cartLength` instead

Comment: thank you for the answer @Murali but your code is not working i am unable to access  the cartLength value from 

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      cartLength: state.shop.cart.length
  }
};

Comment: As metioned in the other answer, you can check `state` value in `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 0):

The value of cartLength need not be added to state and can be directly used from props.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends React {
  render() {
    const { cartLength } = this.props;
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            Ecommerce
          </NavLink>
          <div>
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/cart"}>
                  <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-2" aria-hidden="true" />
                  Cart {cartLength || ""}
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cartLength: state.shop.cart.length,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Header);
```

If you still are not getting the value of cartLength, please console the value inside the mapStateToProps and check whether you are getting it from the right state in store.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   console.log('state',state);
   return {
     cartLength: state.shop.cart.length,
   }
}
```